# Saving Files in Android - For Beginners (Internal / External Storage)

Tags: android-studio, android-external-storage, android-studio-3.1, android-internal-storage, android-studio-3.1.3

I'm very new to android development and I need a beginners help please...

I am creating an app that should have 2 directories, a Databases directory and an Images directory, just like Whatsapp has.

I want to see those directories in the File Manager when I'm browsing my phone, just like you see other apps folders.
I tried everything I found here, to create it in the Internal storage and in the External storage from code. The folders seem to be created, but when I browsed my phone's File Manager, I couldn't find the folder with my app name and inside it my Databases and Images folders...
What am I doing wrong? do I need to create those folders in the android studio as adding folders? or do I need to create it from code?

Can you please give me the actions I need to do to accomplish this task?
I'm using android studio 3.1.3.
Thanks for the helpers! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The terms "*Internal Storage*" and "*External Storage*" might be confusing at first, because Google's intentions are different from what we would expect & know from our day-to-day use of language: "External" doesn't necessarily mean the "SD Card". [This guy made a great article about the terminology confusion](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html)

According to your intentions, you'd want to be working with the **External Storage** concept. The differences are well explained in the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#InternalVsExternalStorage), but I'll shortly brief them to you here.

At the end I'll provide you an example, but first lets know the basics:

**Internal Storage**

- Files are accessible by **only your app**
- Files are removed when your app is uninstalled
- Files are always available (meaning they files will never be saved on a removable memory)

**External Storage**

- Files are fully readable by **other apps** (including any variant of File Manager app, in your case)
- Files aren't necessarily removed when your app is uninstalled - explained later
- Files availability isn't guaranteed (can be deleted by other apps / removable memory)

---

So now that we know you need External Storage, there are several things needed to be done before starting:

- **Require Permissions** (read/write) inside your `Manifest.xml` file, depending on your needs:

```xml
    <manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
    </manifest>
```

Each permission stands by its own, meaning you don't need to have both if, for example, you only wish to read files instead of writing them

- **Verify that [storage is available](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#CheckExternalAvail)** - this is done on runtime, and is well explained inside the documentation. We need to make sure the storage is mounted into the device / its state is not problematic somehow in a way that would cause a failure of read/write requests.

---

### Example Time!

In the given method, we will save a text file inside the root directory.

Credits to [this article](http://www.zoftino.com/saving-files-to-internal-storage-&-external-storage-in-android)

```java
public void writeFileExternalStorage() {

    //Text of the Document
    String textToWrite = "bla bla bla";

    //Checking the availability state of the External Storage.
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

        //If it isn't mounted - we can't write into it.
        return;
    }

    //Create a new file that points to the root directory, with the given name:
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filenameExternal);

    //This point and below is responsible for the write operation
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        //second argument of FileOutputStream constructor indicates whether
        //to append or create new file if one exists
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

        outputStream.write(textToWrite.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

I'd like to answer specifically to some of your questions:

> do I need to create those folders in the android studio as adding folders? or do I need to create it from code?

Definitely not via the Android Studio. These are your projects folder, containing your code. The way to do it is mentioned above.

> I couldn't find the folder with my app name and inside it my Databases and Images folders... What am I doing wrong?

Probably saved your files as Internal Storage ones / saved them as project folders as you mentioned earlier - and those wouldn't (and shouldn't) show up.

---

**Useful things to know**

There are 2 types of directories: public and private.

**Private**

- Not accessible by the Media Store
- Files are removed when app is uninstalled
- Retrieved by `getExternalFilesDir(...)` method

*Example:* the `WhatsApp` directory (in my phone) is located right at the root level. Calling it would be: `getExternalFilesDir("WhatsApp/...")`

**Public** (Downloads/Movies/Images libraries)

- Files are scanned by the [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore)
- Retrieved by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(...)` method

*Example:* getting the `Documents` folder would look like: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed and fast answer! just one more question about it. the path on my phone of the file I created is: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.../files/FileName, when I used getExternalFilesDir. I wanted to create the directories on: /storage/emulated/0/AppName, so I used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). On debug, the path was correct and the folder seemed to be created, but I can't find it on the phone and on the pc browse. where did I wrong here? for WhatsApp, for example, the path is /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/

Comment: The code I used to create the folder is:

String DirName = "MyAppName";

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DirName );
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

Comment: I think you want to use `new File(getExternalFilesDir(), DirName)` instead of `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. Another thing: File is supposed to point at a File, and not a Directory. try to change DirName to "MyAppName/TestFile.txt" and see if it works for you

Comment: With getExternalFilesDir(), the path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.../DirName/files/, and I want the path to be /storage/emulated/0/DirName/. is using new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DirName ) fot this is not correct? and for the changing DirName to "MyAppName/TestFile.txt", I want to create an empty dir and fill it with the app commands in code, is there other way to do that? and why I don't see the created dir? thanks again for all the help! :) (תודה רבה!)

Comment: And what is the correct way to create an empty dir by not using File?

Comment: I'm sorry - was confused about the `getExternalFilesDir`. I found out what your problem might be (I tried it myself now, it works) - its a permission issue: go to your phone settings -> apps -> find your app and set Storage permission to true. Also, before you publish your app - you'd want to make a popup dialog requesting the permission for users with android version > 6 (Marshmallow). the permission setting in the `Manifest.xml` isn't enough for Marshmallow and above. Try and let me know if it worked.
בכיף :)

Comment: Yes, it worked! that was the issue! Thanks, you helped me a lot! :) מאד מעריכה, תודה רבה! :)

Comment: `outputStream.write(cashback.getBytes())` - I think you meant `textToWrite`, not `cashback`. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The main answer really helped me out and I couldn't have gotten to this without that great answer.

But I had a few difficulties with getting the storage directory (because of changes to API over time) and I'm using Kotlin so I thought I'd just share my final code that I used.

Mine also returns a String message (absolute path to the file is success, and error message otherwise).

I've also added some Log statements so you can watch what is happening.

```
fun writeFileExternalStorage() :String {

        var fileData : String = "test this"
        
        Log.i("FirstFrag", "in writeFileExternalStorage")
        //Checking the availability state of the External Storage.
        val state = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED != state) {

            Log.i("FirstFrag", "Couldn't get file system.")
            return "Couldn't write file."
        }

        var file =File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "test.txt")

        Log.i("FirstFrag", file.absolutePath)
        //This point and below is responsible for the write operation
        var outputStream: FileOutputStream? = null
        try {
            Log.i("FirstFrag", "creating new file")
            file.createNewFile()
            Log.i("FirstFrag", "file created")
            //second argument of FileOutputStream constructor indicates whether
            //to append or create new file if one exists
            outputStream = FileOutputStream(file, true)
            outputStream?.write(fileData.toByteArray())
            outputStream?.flush()
            outputStream?.close()
            Log.i("FirstFrag", "wrote file!")
            return file.absolutePath
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.i("FirstFrag",e.message.toString())
            return e.message.toString() + "\nPlease check that you have a valid filename."
        }
        finally {
            isRetrievingFile = false;
        }
    }
```